# all most vs almost

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice, quantifiers

We can use "almost" not "all most" in this sentence.

> When I tried to get a train ticket, (   ) the seats were already taken.

"all most" is grammatical? and if not, why isn't it grammatical?

Comment: "all most" is not correct at all, "all of most" you mean?

Answer (score 4):

"All" and "most" are two different words that can be used individually to represent quantity/extent, they cannot be combined.

"Almost" is a different word that is used as a modifier to "all", to indicate that its not affecting 100% but a large majority.

So, you could say:

> When I tried to get a train ticket, **all** the seats were already taken.

i.e. There were **no seats** available at all.

> When I tried to get a train ticket, **most of** the seats were already taken.

i.e. There were just a **few seats** available.

> When I tried to get a train ticket, **almost all** the seats were already taken.

i.e. Similar as above, there were a **few seats** available.

In general use, it would be the following order that tends to be used:

1. All (indicating 100%)
2. Almost all (not quite 100% but nearly there)
3. Most (a large majority)
4. Many (a majority, though closer to 50%)
5. Some
6. Few (a few steps above 0%)
7. Almost none
8. None (indicating 0%)

Comment: A very clear and nicely organized answer. I will use it with a student I am volunteering with.

Comment: thank you for your answer! very easy to understand them!

Comment: It's not quite true that "all" and "most" can't be combined - though they can't be combined in that order.  In colloquial AmE, "most all" is another way of saying "almost all".  (Halfway down the page at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/most , there's a definition of "most" as meaning "almost".)  This isn't possible in British English, of course.  Btw, I wouldn't necessarily agree that "many" means a majority (it may mean a substantial number but less than half) or that "most" means a large majority (often it does, but it sometimes means a simple majority).